# Need query to find all entries with predicates and distinct values of an attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api

I have a java object with an attribute "bracketID". This attribute is not unique. I need a query that gives me all objects depending on the set predicates and a distinct attribute "bracketID".

Given Objects:
bracketId: 1
bracketId: 2
bracketId: 3
bracketId: 3
bracketId: 3

Needed Result:
bracketId: 1
bracketId: 2
bracketId: 3

Important is that I can still set any predicate to filter for example.

Im am new to all this and have no idea how to solve this

```
 @Override
    public List<UIJobData> getJobs( final String listType, final String filter, final String sortDirection,
                                    final String sortHeader, final Integer pageIndex, final Integer pageSize )
    {
        final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<UIJobData> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery( UIJobData.class );
        final Root<UIJobData> jobData = criteriaQuery.from( UIJobData.class );

        final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        addListTypeToPredicates( listType, criteriaBuilder, jobData, predicates );
        addFilterToPredicates( filter, predicates, criteriaBuilder, jobData );

        criteriaQuery.select( jobData ).where(  predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]) );

        setSortToCriteriaQuery( sortDirection, sortHeader, criteriaBuilder, criteriaQuery, jobData );

        final TypedQuery<UIJobData> query = m_entityManager.createQuery( criteriaQuery );
        setPagination( pageIndex, pageSize, query );

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    private void addListTypeToPredicates( final String listType, final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, final Root<UIJobData> jobData,
        final List<Predicate> predicates )
    {
        if( listType != null && !listType.isEmpty())
        {
            predicates.add( criteriaBuilder.like( jobData.get( "listType" ), listType ) );
        }
    }

    private void addFilterToPredicates( final String filter, final List<Predicate> predicates, final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, final Root<UIJobData> jobData )
    {
        if( filter != null && !filter.isEmpty() )
        {
            final Predicate id = criteriaBuilder.like( jobData.get( "idString" ), "%" + filter + "%" );
            final Predicate orderName = criteriaBuilder.like( criteriaBuilder.lower( jobData.get( "orderName" ) ), "%" + filter.toLowerCase() + "%" );

            predicates.add( criteriaBuilder.or( id, orderName ) );
        }
    }

    private void setSortToCriteriaQuery( final String sortDirection, final String sortHeader, final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
                               final CriteriaQuery<UIJobData> criteriaQuery, final Root<UIJobData> jobData )
    {
        if( sortDirection != null && !sortDirection.isEmpty() && sortHeader != null && !sortHeader.isEmpty() )
        {
            switch( sortDirection )
            {
                case "asc":
                    criteriaQuery.orderBy( criteriaBuilder.asc( jobData.get( sortHeader ) ) );
                    break;
                case "desc":
                    criteriaQuery.orderBy( criteriaBuilder.desc( jobData.get( sortHeader ) ) );
                    break;
                default:
                    criteriaQuery.orderBy( criteriaBuilder.asc( jobData.get( sortHeader ) ) );
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            criteriaQuery.orderBy( criteriaBuilder.asc( jobData.get( "id" ) ) );
        }
    }

    private void setPagination( final Integer pageIndex, final Integer pageSize, final TypedQuery<UIJobData> query )
    {
        if( pageIndex != null && pageIndex >= 0 && pageSize != null && pageSize >= 0 )
        {
            query.setFirstResult( ( pageIndex ) * pageSize );
            query.setMaxResults( pageSize );
        }
    }
```

Given Objects including:
bracketId: 1
bracketId: 2
bracketId: 3
bracketId: 3
bracketId: 3

Needed Result including:
bracketId: 1
bracketId: 2
bracketId: 3

Answer (score 0):

Is it an Option to leave the query as it is and replace the result instead? 
Something like the following:
(Assuming your bracketID is an Integer)

```
List<UIJobData> list = query.getResultList();

ConcurrentMap<Integer, List<UIJobData>> map = list.parallelStream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(UIJobData::getBracketID));

List<UIJobData> result = new ArrayList<UIJobdata>();
for(int i : map.keySet()){
    result.add(map.get(i).get(0));
}

return result;
```